# Force apt-get not to upgrade a custom package dkpg

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, redis

I've created my own deb package for Redis 2.6.11 instead of the very old default version for Ubuntu. All works well except when I do an `apt-get upgrade` it tries to install what it thinks is the latest version of `redis-server` How can tell the package manager to stick on my custom one and don't refer to default repository for this particular package?

Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your package the same as the "official" distro package.